# Windows QML: Fix hanging Rectangle after changing height of main Window

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

In Qt Creator I have a QML Window with a "more" Button at the bottom. If one clicks the botton the window expands or decrease, depending on the state.

This works fine with Kubuntu, but with Windows 10 the button stays in the middle, and only the lower button works an next click.

**Sceenshoots:**

Kubuntu 15.10

```
~$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.4.2 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

[image: kubuntu with half window]
[image: kubuntu with full window]

Windows 10

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin>qmake.exe --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/mingw492_32/lib
```

[image: windows with full window and wrong button]

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: main
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 100
    maximumHeight: 200
    maximumWidth: 200

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangleMoreButton
        height: 40
        width: parent.width
        color: "#4a4a4a"
        border.color: "#ffffff"
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0

        Text {
            id: textMoreButton
            text: "more"
            color: "#ffffff"
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                rectangleMoreButton.state == 'more' ? rectangleMoreButton.state = "" : rectangleMoreButton.state = 'more'
            }
        }

        states: [
            State {
                name: "more"
                    onCompleted: {
                    textMoreButton.text = "less"
                    main.height = 200
                }
            },
            State {
                name: ""
                onCompleted: {
                    textMoreButton.text = "more"
                    main.height = 100
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How could I update the position the "more"/"less" Rectangle button after changing the height of main Window in QML to solve this problem? Is there a way for a force update or repainting the window if the height changes?

**Edit for Workaround:**

I found a Workaround to fix the hanging Button in Windows: Add a timer, which runs only once with a millisecond time offset after the resizing of the window:

```
Timer {
    id: timerUpdateMoreButton
    interval: 1
    onTriggered: {
        rectangleMoreButton.y = main.y
        timerUpdateMoreButton.running = false
    }
}
```

and for the "more" state, the timer has to activated:

```
timerUpdateMoreButton.running = true
```

Comment: What Qt/QML version do you use? I've tested the code with Qt 5.6 and it works as expected.

Comment: @folibis I was using Qt 5.5.1 with MinGW 4.9.2, but after removing and updating to Qt 5.6.0 and rebuilding the project from above the problem still exists.